# Logging in to Sharepoint - behaviour changes every few minutes

Tags: sharepoint-services

Super curious one here today, guys.

We have Sharepoint Services 3.0 running on a farm of two physical Win2008 machines.

It has been running great for well over 5 years now.  No changes have been made on the server-side for years.

Yesterday reports started to come in of users not being able to log in.  Regardless the user and the password, Sharepoint would prompt for credentials 3 times before just going to a blank white page.

Had been playing with the popular suggestions of using Compatibility View in IE 10 and 11.  But no difference. Have also been reading about registry changes and permissions changes. None of it has helped.

What I noticed today is even weirder.

I will go to our Sharepoint site, it will prompt for credentials and not let me in.  But if I wait 5-10 minutes, it randomly starts working again!  Then wait another 10 minutes and it's no longer working.  It's been toggling back and forth all morning.

I've found that manually restarting the Sharepoint Services Search service will get it going again.... for about 10 minutes.  Then it goes back to toggling back and forth between working, and not working.

I'm completely stumped.  Anyone run into anything like this before? Or have any suggestions for me?

TIA!

Comment: `No changes have been made on the server-side for years` - Really? You haven't installed any Windows Updates in the time that the server has been running?

Comment: Sad but true.  Inherited this server, don't know anything about it, currently Windows Update just errors, I think it's a Group Policy issue. *edit* just checked, last reboot was Oct 4 2013. I think I'll reboot it overnight tonight.